# Why creating Anaconda environments is taking forever

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm interested in using a nice script from GitLab:
https://gitlab.com/RBP_Bioinformatics/mustard

Now the author already describes nicely the requirements and dependencies of the script, however, I really get tough time trying to creat an environment via conda

```
$ conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working...
```

now it has been solving the environment forever now, and I seem not to be the only one suffering,

honstly, I think that PIP and VENV are still the best, and I can't understand the use of a script when I must understand all the dependencies and packages to run it one single time, it would have been easier to write it from the beginning!

also I think when a script has so many dependencies, efforts should be done to compile that , that's why compiling is for,

anyway, I will need help in creating an environment using conda without waiting for 6h or more ..

I must be doing something not smart, and I don't want to work hard!

thanks if you decide to help!

Comment: You might wanna give `mamba` a try. It's a very fast drop-in replacement for conda. You can get it via `conda install -c conda-forge mamba` and then use  it just like conda: `mamba create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`. Note however that you need to install mamba in a python3 environment, as python2.7 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Creating a condo virtual environment takes seconds, not hours.  Did you load Python 2.7 from your Anaconda distribution?

Comment: I am having the same issue when following instructions to install fermitools. from here: https://github.com/fermi-lat/Fermitools-conda/wiki/Quickstart-Guide     I followed the instructions, installed miniconda, then :   conda create -n fermi -c conda-forge -c fermi fermitools python=3 clhep=2.4.4.1    ;  it has been more than 12 hours in the run. Showing "Executing transaction: \ /" forever...

Answer (score 6):

Consider trying

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

without the *anaconda* at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you still try to create the environment with a file say requirements.txt, as I tried... I was having an issue where Anaconda Navigator will stay loading the file forever, with no errors.  I ended up creating the environment using the following command.

Hope this works for any OCD person like me that was trying to learn how to create an environment from the requirements.txt
(MAKE SURE THE FILE IS IN THE SAME DIRECTORY)

```
conda create --name my-env-name --file requirements.txt
```